# Initialize enum value with function call

Tags: c++, enums

Is there any way to initialize enum value like this:

```
enum Test
{
    X = function("X")
};
```

Currently in Visual Studio I get this error:

> error C2057: expected constant expression

And Visual Studio doesn't support **constexpr**

Comment: _"And Visual Studio doesn't support constexpr"_ It should, using the -std=c++11 compile flag.

Comment: I don't think there is a way this can work without `constexpr` since `enum` constants themselves can (must be possible to) be used in `constexpr`essions.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx

Comment: A dirty way and (probably buggy) way would be to use `#define function(x) 1` .

Comment: @P0W THX, for clarifying (I'm so happy I don't have to work with VS)!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ That's a g++ option, not a VS one.  And as POW points out, Microsoft doesn't claim support for `constexpr` in any of the versions currently available.

Comment: @JamesKanze That depends on your definition of "available". The Visual C++ November 2013 CTP has a largely (but not entirely) complete implementation of `constexpr`. Presumably the VS2014 preview does too.

Comment: Thank you everyone. I'm using VS2013 Update 4 CTP and constexpr still not available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The enumerator list within an enum declaration is defined as follows:

enumerator-list -   comma-separated list of enumerator definitions, each of which is either simply an identifier, which becomes the name of the enumerator, or an identifier with an initializer: identifier = constexpr

You may only use constant expressions.